# Replace instead of Remove File Image

Tags: jquery

I'm not a good user of JQuery as I used to program many years in the past. May I kindly as for your Support?
I would need this script but instead of deleting the file fields, I would need to have it replaced by a placeholder Image when sending the form (let's say - blank.jpg instead of ""). What code would I need? Kind regards

```
$(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(){
    $("input:file", this).filter(function(){
      return ($(this).val().length == 0);
    }).remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: I\m not sure I understand what you mean. Is it that while the form is beeing sent you want to display a picture in the place where the form was or what exactly is it? Because when the form is submitted it usually leads the user to another page (so it can send the data through GET or POST)

Comment: The form offers to upload e.g. 5 images. the form will be stored in a DB and will be sent as an email to the client as well to a confirmation page. The email can only illustrate an image if there was one uploaded. If there's no image, I get this ugly X. Therefore, I would require to replace the Image file form field (the empty once only) by e.g. a blank.gif. it sends POST.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to check the values on the server side. Supposing you use PHP to program your application you would chech if there is no file on the field (one of the 5 fields you have) and if it is so then store the 'blank.jpg' as a value in the database.

Something like:

```
if($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 4) {
// the error 4 means there is no file uploaded

//store correct path and values for 'blank.jpg' in DB (set in your query)
}
```

If it would help here is a [quick overview on PHP file upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

However if your only option is to do it with JQuery then unfortunately it is not possible.

For security reasons, browsers prevent javascript from changing the files which will be uploaded: only the user can select files via the user interface. This is to prevent an evil script to upload for example password from the users computer, without the user knowing.

The one exception is that calling "reset" on the form will clear the file or filelist, but you can never add to programmatically.